# React Native Search Dropdown

Tags: react-native, dropdown

I'm working on React native app. I'm looking for a searchable dropdown which I need to implement in many places.

Below see below video for reference:

[Sample Video](https://vimeo.com/user90135307/review/292708261/412ff6b4a8)

I have implemented below third parties but they are not same as I need:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-searchable-dropdown
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-searchable-selectbox
3. https://github.com/toystars/react-native-multiple-select

Answer (score 4):

I tried implementing something similar a while ago and at the time I dropped the idea of having a drop down as it was inconsistent on both platforms & I could not find a perfect solution. I cannot see your video but I think I know where you're going with this. 
Here is my advice:
I would create a separate screen that opens on the tap on this component that would be a 'dropdown', and in there create a searchable/filtrable list. You could try doing that using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/searchable-flatlist, or create your own flatlist, which is super easy and allows for more customization!
EDIT: 
If you don't want a separate screen use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-searchable-dropdown

Comment: I don't want to create a new page actually, wants this feature on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

try implementing one :

```
const sports = ["Badminton","Cricket","Chess","Kho-Kho","Kabbadi","Hockey","Boxing","Football","Basketball","Volleyball","Tennis","Table Tennis"];

predict(){
    let q = this.state.query;
    let arr = sports.filter(ele => ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) != -1).splice(0,5);
    this.setState((prev = this.state)=>{
        let obj={};
        Object.assign(obj,prev);
        obj.predictions.splice(0,obj.predictions.length);
        arr.forEach(ele=>{
            obj.predictions.push({key : ele});
        });
        return obj;
    });
}

<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>{this.setState({done : true})}}>
                <ScrollView
                    keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
                    contentContainerStyle={style.content}
                >
                    <View>
                        <TextInput 
                            onChangeText={(text)=>{
                                this.setState({query : text , done : false});
                                this.predict();
                            }}  
                            placeholder="What do you want to play ?" 
                            placeholderTextColor="#A6A4A4"
                            value = {this.state.query}
                            onSubmitEditing = {()=>{this.setState({done : true})}}
                            underlineColorAndroid = "#0098fd"
                        ></TextInput>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.filteredEvents()}}><Icon name="search" color = "#0098fd" size = {20}></Icon></TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>


                    {
                        this.state.predictions.length != 0 && !this.state.done &&
                        <FlatList 
                            style={styles.predictor_view}
                            data={this.state.predictions}
                            extraData = {this.state}
                            renderItem = {
                                ({item})=>(
                                        <TouchableOpacity 
                                        style={styles.predictions} 
                                        onPress={()=>{
                                            console.log('ok');
                                            this.setState({query : item.key,done : true});
                                            console.log(this.state);
                                        }}>
                                            <Text>{item.key}</Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                )
                            }
                        />
                    }
                </ScrollView>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: Please post the whole code please, this is just some stuff in the `render()` method. Major functions like `filteredEvents()` are missing

Comment: I think you can implement such function on your own  , keep predict out of render and make other functions which you will like to have similarly to predict. And keep sports variable out of the class .

Answer (score 0):

I have used [react-native-autocomplete-input](https://github.com/mrlaessig/react-native-autocomplete-input)

I have written a component to help in the dropdown:
customDropDownComponent.js

```js
/*This is an example of AutoComplete Input/ AutoSuggestion Input*/
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Button, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
//import all the components we are going to use.
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input'
//import Autocomplete component


class CustomDropDownComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //Initialization of state
        //films will contain the array of suggestion
        //query will have the input from the autocomplete input
        this.state = {
            query: '',
            data: [],
            dataDuplicate:[],
            itemSelected: false
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      //Loading all data
        this.loadData()


    }
    
    findElement(query, text, itemSelected) {
        //method called everytime when we change the value of the inputquery === '' || 
        if (itemSelected === true||query==='') {
            //if the query is null or an item is selected then return blank
            return [];
        }
        //making a case insensitive regular expression to get similar value from the data json
        const regex = new RegExp(`${query.trim()}`, 'i');
        //return the filtered data array according the query from the input
        var newList = [];
        var result = this.state.IATADup.filter(data => {
            if (data.id.search(regex) === 0) {
                newList.push(data);
                return false;
            } else {
                return data.id.search(regex) >= 0;
            }
        });
        result = newList.concat(result);
        this.props.adjustMargin(1, result.length);//expadnding space in page to make room for dropdown
        this.setState({ data: result, query: text, itemSelected: itemSelected });
    }

    loadData = () => {
        var dataToLoad = Commondata.aircraftDetail
        dataToLoad.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.id > b.id) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (b.id > a.id) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
        this.setState({
            dataDuplicate: dataToLoad
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { query } = this.state;
        const data = this.state.data;
        const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();
        var inputContainerStyle = styles.inputContainerStyle;
        if (this.props.destinationBorder === "#FF0000") {
            inputContainerStyle = styles.inputContainerRedStyle;
        }

        return (

            <View style={styles.container}  >
                <Autocomplete
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    flatListProps={{ nestedScrollEnabled: true }}
                    containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
                    listStyle={styles.listStyle}
                    inputContainerStyle={inputContainerStyle}
                    data={data}
                    keyExtractor={(item, i) => { return i } 
                    defaultValue={query}
                    onChangeText={text => {
                        //handle input
                        if (text.trim() === "") this.props.adjustMarginBack();//adjust margin to normal in case of empty searrch element
                        this.findElement(text, text, false);//search for element
                    }}
                    placeholder={en.pick_one}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        //you can change the view you want to show in suggestion from here
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                            this.props.adjustMarginBack()
                            this.setState({ query: item.id, itemSelected: true, data: [] });
                        }}>
                            <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                                {item.id}
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.itemSubText}>
                                {item.name}
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                />


            </View>

        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    autocompleteContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        borderWidth: 0,

    },
    inputContainerStyle: {
        borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: '#D9D9D9', padding: '1.5%'
    },
    inputContainerRedStyle: {
        borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: '#FF0000', padding: '1.5%'
    },
    descriptionContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: '5%'
    },
    itemText: {
        fontSize: 15,
        paddingTop: 5,
        paddingBottom: 5,
        margin: 2,
    },
    itemSubText: {
        fontSize: 10,
        paddingTop: 5,
        paddingBottom: 5,
        margin: 2,
        marginLeft: 10
    },
    infoText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    listStyle: {
        height: 100,
        position: "relative",
        zIndex: 999
    }
});
export default CustomComponent;
```

Now in the display screen:

app.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import CustomDropDownComponent from './CustomDropDownComponent.js'

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ScrollView
                    nestedScrollEnabled={true}
                    keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>
                    <CustomDropDownComponent /*Handle all inputs and margin resets as props *//>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```